# Getting location of IconButton tap event

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use showMenu() to display a pop up menu when a IconButton is clicked. But IconButton doesn't give the tap event data that contains the offset. Is there something I'm missing here? How can I get the menu to show in the place of the tap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GestureDetector`'s `onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {}` callback to get the details if a Tap event is successfully triggered.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is using `InkWell`.

```
InkWell(
     customBorder: CircleBorder(),  //<-- for circular splash effect on tap like IconButton
     child: Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
       child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
     ),
     onTapDown: (details) => print(details.globalPosition),
     onTap: (){},
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` to detect the tap position of the IconButton. It can be extracted from the IconButton's **key context** with `.findRenderObject() as RenderBox`...

The hardest part is to get the correct parameters for the `RelativeRect.fromLTRB()` that you give back to `position` of the `showMenu()` function. I might be wrong but I find the key params are *right* and *bottom* if the context menu is supposed to display on left hand side of IconButton and vice versa (*left* and *top*) for displaying it on the right hand side of IconButton.

```
// Create a `GlobalKey` for your `IconButton`
GlobalKey actionsKey = GlobalKey();

// Wherever your IconButton is...
IconButton(
  // Pass the key to the IconButton
  key: actionsKey,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  onPressed: () async {
    // Get the screen size
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    
    // Find the global positioning offset
    RenderBox renderBox = actionsKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    // Show the menu with the position calculated from the tap offset
    await showMenu(
      context: context, // or; Get.context!,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        offset.dx,
        offset.dy,
        Get.width - offset.dx,
        Get.height - offset.dy,
      ),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: const Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.flag_outlined),
              _sizedBox,
              Text('Flag as inappropriate'),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint('Flag as inappropriate');
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

[image: context menu]

Hope this helps.